# Bug in MS Word's VBA Document Collection, not sure why this workaround crashes

Tags: vba, ms-word

MS Word 2010 has a bug in its ability to correctly maintain *(of all things)* the documents collection ([link to earliest report found - social.msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/a91e8ee3-5181-4107-a518-402382305683/word-20032007-addins-not-working-on-word-2010-due-to-corrupted-document-collection-object?forum=worddev)).

As far as I can tell this bug only impacts Word 2010. Although the documents collection is not maintained, it turns out that the `Application.Windows` collection is. Hence, for Word 2010 the following code based on the original reporters investigation (see below) and [this question on answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/problem-with-vba-to-verify-number-of-open/0ff990a0-4ae3-4a6a-80c1-d250bbb4c86c?auth=1) seem to provide a good alternative to the buggy documents collection:

```
' PURPOSE:
' Return a document collection, work-around for Word 2010 bug
Public Function docCollection() As VBA.Collection
    Dim indexOfAvailableAppWindows As Long
    Dim resultDoc As VBA.Collection
    Dim foundDoc As Word.Document
    Set resultDoc = New Collection

    For indexOfAvailableAppWindows = 1 To Application.Windows.Count
        If Application.Windows(indexOfAvailableAppWindows).Document.Type = wdTypeDocument Then
            Set foundDoc = Application.Windows(indexOfAvailableAppWindows).Document
            resultDoc.Add foundDoc, foundDoc.FullName ' Can NOT use 'name' - fails to be unique 
        End If
    Next indexOfAvailableAppWindows

    Set docCollection = resultDoc
    Set resultDoc = Nothing

End Function
```

However, and **here's my question**, the above code some times fails with error 457 This key is already associated with an element of this collection on line `resultDoc.Add foundDoc, foundDoc.FullName`.  **What circumstances could possibly lead to such a failure?**

So far the code has only failed on 1 PC running Word 2016. I don't have access to the PC. I did discover that the original version used Document.Name as the key (which was not always unique, so this was changed to Document.Full name)

Assumptions:

- `Document.FullName` will always be unique

Things I've ruled out:

- use of Split Window
- opening downloaded documents *(protected window documents are not counted)*

Code that can be used to demonstrate the issue in Word 2010 (adapted from the original report).

```
' Function Credit Bas258 (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/bas258)
Function test01() As Boolean
    'Adapted to VBA from original: 03-11-2012 1.0 Visual Studio 2008 VB code

    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oDoc0 As Word.Document
    Dim oDoc1 As Word.Document
    Dim oDoc2 As Word.Document
    Dim oDoc3 As Word.Document
    Dim oDoc4 As Word.Document

    Dim n As Integer

    Set WDapp = Application

    With WDapp
        Debug.Print (Format(Now(), "dd-MM-yyyy") & "  MS Office " & .Application.Version)

        Set oDoc0 = .Documents.Add: Debug.Print ("add " & oDoc0.Name)
        Set oDoc1 = .Documents.Add: Debug.Print ("add " & oDoc1.Name)
        Set oDoc2 = .Documents.Add: Debug.Print ("add " & oDoc2.Name)
        Set oDoc3 = .Documents.Add: Debug.Print ("add " & oDoc3.Name)
        Set oDoc4 = .Documents.Add: Debug.Print ("add " & oDoc4.Name)

        For n = 1 To .Documents.Count
            Debug.Print ("count " & n & "  " & .Documents(n).Name)
        Next n

        Debug.Print ("close " & oDoc4.Name)
        oDoc4.Close
        Set oDoc4 = Nothing
        Debug.Print ("close " & oDoc3.Name)
        oDoc3.Close
        Set oDoc3 = Nothing

        For n = 1 To .Documents.Count
            Debug.Print ("count " & n & "  " & .Documents(n).Name)
        Next n

        n = 0
        For Each oDoc In .Documents
            n = n + 1
            Debug.Print ("doc " & n & "  " & oDoc.Name)
        Next oDoc

        n = 0
        For Each oWin In .Windows
            n = n + 1
            Debug.Print ("win " & n & " " & oWin.Document.Name)
        Next oWin

        Debug.Print ("close " & oDoc2.Name)
        oDoc2.Close
        Set oDoc2 = Nothing

        Debug.Print ("close " & oDoc1.Name)
        oDoc1.Close
        Set oDoc1 = Nothing

        Debug.Print ("close " & oDoc0.Name)
        oDoc0.Close
        Set oDoc0 = Nothing

    End With

    Set WDapp = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a setting in MS Word that enables 1 document to be viewed in 2 windows. In Word 2010 it is under the View (Tab): Window > New Window

The new window is counted separately in `Application.Windows.Count` and returns the same document object, hence the key exists.

```
For indexOfAvailableAppWindows = 1 To Application.Windows.Count  ' <<< New Windows is counted
    If Application.Windows(indexOfAvailableAppWindows).Document.Type = wdTypeDocument Then
        Set foundDoc = Application.Windows(indexOfAvailableAppWindows).Document
        resultDoc.Add foundDoc, foundDoc.FullName ' <<< fails to add 2nd instance of document
    End If
```

[image]

So... the solution would likely involve checking the caption of the document:

```
IMMEDIATE WINDOW:
 ?foundDoc.Windows(1).Caption
 Document2:1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT going to be the accepted answer. Although it does answer the broader question (what could cause this code to crash) it not address the specific crash that I am trying to isolate. Either way there appears to be another bug in MS Word which seemed to be worth capturing for the common good.

This time the bug is with the Windows Collection; and joy of joys, I've confirmed it for both Word 2010 and Word 2016 - both 64 bit apps.

Steps to reproduce the bug are as follows:

- In windows explorer enable the Preview Pane
- Select a word document FILE so that it is 'previewed'
- Open the same document (without losing the 'preview view')
- Run the code from the OP, it will crash on this line:

  - `If Application.Windows(indexOfAvailableAppWindows).Document.Type = wdTypeDocument Then`

It turns out that when a word file is being previewed the `Application.Windows.Count` property is incremented by the preview; however any attempt to get a property of that window results in Error 5097 - Word has encountered a problem.

So, an improvement to the original code would therefore be:

```
' PURPOSE:
' Returns a healthy document collection
'   - work-around for Word 2010 bug
'   - excludes hits from Windows Explorer Preview Pane
Public Function docCollection() As VBA.Collection
    On Error GoTo docCollectionError
    Dim indexOfAvailableAppWindows As Long
    Dim resultDoc As VBA.Collection
    Dim foundDoc As Word.Document
    Set resultDoc = New Collection

    ' Use index instead of Each to avoid For Loop Not initialised error, preview pane
    For indexOfAvailableAppWindows = 1 To Application.Windows.Count
        If Application.Windows(indexOfAvailableAppWindows).Document.Type = wdTypeDocument Then
            Set foundDoc = Application.Windows(indexOfAvailableAppWindows).Document
            resultDoc.Add foundDoc, foundDoc.FullName ' Key must NOT be 'name' - fails to be unique see BUG: 1315
        End If
lblSkipThisDoc:
    Next indexOfAvailableAppWindows

    Set docCollection = resultDoc
    Set resultDoc = Nothing

Exit:
    Exit Function

docCollectionError:
    If Err.Number = 5097 Then   ' An open document is also open in the Windows Explorer Preview Pane
        Err.Clear
        Resume lblSkipThisDoc   ' - skip this window
    End If

    If Err.Number = 457 Then    ' Key is already used, but HOW? Unknown cause of error
        Err.Clear
        Stop 'Resume lblSkipThisDoc   ' Is it safe to skip this document, why is there a duplicate?
    End If

End Function
```